# Finding x given that $\lim_{n\to\infty } x^{x^{n-1}}=5$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Given a sequence $\{a_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ defined in the following way: 
$ a_1=x, \ a_2=x^x, \  a_3=x^{x^{x}}, a_4=x^{x^{x^{x}}} ... \ (x>0)$ 
what would be the value of $x$ if  $\lim_{n\to\infty } a_n=5$

Comment: Your title and question don't describe the same sequence

Comment: Your title does not match your question.  The title has no solution as if $x \gt 1$ the limit is infinite and if $0 \lt x \le 1$ the limit is $1$

Comment: what would be the correct representation of $a_n$ as in the description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me that you mean tetration. It is commonly written as $^nx$

You mean what is the limit for $lim_{n \to \infty}\,^nx$

That limit only exists for $0 \leq x \leq e^{e^{-1}}$

If $0 \leq x < e^{-e}$  then the limit is a periodic square wave function, whose max and min values are the solution to $x^{x^c}=c$ (x is the constant, and c the limit). You have 2 limit values, $c_1$ and $c_2$.

If $ e^{-e} \leq x \leq e^{e^{-1}}$  then the limit is the solution to the equation $x^c=c$. The limit c is calculated using the [lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

${}^{\infty}x = x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}} = c = \frac{\mathrm{W}(-\ln{x})}{-\ln{x}} $

Given that $x=e^{e^{-1}}$ is the maximum value for which you have a limit, there is no limit for $^nx=5$.

But there is a limit for $lim_{n \to \infty} \,^{-n}x=5$, if $^0x$ is defined as $^0x>lim_{n \to \infty} \,^{n}x$. In such case, $x\approx 1,3797296901083$

That's because there is some arbitrariness in defining $^0x$. It is commonly defined as $^0x=1$, but that's just a (sensible) choice.

Yet $^nx$ is not $x^{x^{n-1}}$ (as you wrote in the title). The solution to $\lim_{n\to\infty } x^{x^{n-1}}=z$ is z because for the solution to exist, it should be $z^z=z$. But z=5 does not meet the requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Let

$$\zeta = x^{x^{x^{...}}}$$

We know that

$$\zeta = 5$$

Since:

$$\zeta = x^{x^{x^{...}}}$$

We can say that:

$$\zeta = x^{\zeta}$$

Thus, you can solve for x using $5 = x^5$.

Comment: This will not work, as if $x=\sqrt[5] 5$ the limit diverges.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish: I think the sequence does converge when $x=\sqrt[5] 5$, but to about $\zeta=1.76492\ldots$ rather than $5$

Comment: Yep, just wrote some MATLAB code to figure out that convergence. That's really weird, the idea behind my solution works for x^(x^...) = 2.

Comment: The problem is that $F(y)=y^{1/y}$ is not 1-to-1 for $x>1.$ The value $y=1.76492...$ satisfies $y^{1/y}=5^{1/5}.$  When $1<x\leq e^{1/e},$  the sequence x^(x^...) converges to $ A$ where $x=A^{1/A}\leq e^{1/e},$and $A\leq e$, but if $x>e^{1/e}$ the sequences goes to infinity.  An amusing result of your method is that if you assume a limit of $4$ you get $x=4^{1/4}=\sqrt 2$ but if you put assume a limit of $2$ you also get $x=\sqrt 2$.